# Using two textures in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, textures

I am writing a program in which I have to use two different textures.  I can get one file read in and used as a texture but have so far been unable to get two textures to work.  Here is my code to set up the one texture that I have:

```
        FILE *fd;
        int k, nm;
        char c;
        int i, i;
        char b[256];
        float s;
        int red, green, blue;

        fd = fopen("AI_Lab.ppm", "r");

        // check first line for P3
        fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]", b);
        if (b[0] != 'P' || b[1] != '3') {
                 printf("%s is not a PPM file\n", b);
                 system("pause");
                 exit(0);
                 }
        // skip comments
        fscanf(fd, "%c%c", &c, &c);
        while (c == '#') {
              fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]", b);
              fscanf(fd, "%c%c", &c, &c);
        }

        // put back first character of first non-comment line
        ungetc(c, fd);
        // read file info
        fscanf(fd, "%d %d %d", &o, &m, &k);

        nm = o * m; // overall size

        image = malloc(3*sizeof(GLuint)*nm);

        s = 255./k;

        for (i=0; i<nm; i++) {
            fscanf(fd, "%d %d %d", &red, &green, &blue);
            image[3*nm - 3*i - 3] = red;
            image[3*nm - 3*i - 2] = green;
            image[3*nm - 3*i - 1] = blue;
        }

        glPixelTransferf(GL_RED_SCALE, s);
        glPixelTransferf(GL_GREEN_SCALE, s);
        glPixelTransferf(GL_BLUE_SCALE, s);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SWAP_BYTES, GL_TRUE);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, o1, m1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, image);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

I have tried all I can think of and cannot get things to work correctly.

Comment: Look up `glGenTextures` and `glBindTexture`, which let you operate on texture objects. What you're using is the notion of the "default texture". Beyond not supporting more than one texture, this usage model is also deprecated.

Comment: Is there any way that I could work glGenTextures into the existing code or should I scrap it and start over?  (I am using glBindTexture later in my code).

Comment: You can add it to the existing code if you want. You'll need a set of those two calls somewhere before the `glTexImage2D` call.

Comment: So do I read my other file in and then do that?  I'm sort of confused.

Comment: yes you can build `glGenTextures` into your existing code.  You MUST store the texture number that is generated in `glGenTextures`, so that you have something to pass to `glBintTexture`.  You might want to create a texture loading function that takes a filename, and returns the texture number.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I created the texture loading function like you suggested and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your texture specification looks to be alright, but you'll need to brush up on the basics of OpenGL.  The red-book is a good place to start.

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html

Head on down to the section on `Texture Objects`.

Before calling `glTexImage2d`, you will want to generate and bind a new texture object.  Each one of your textures should have its own object!

When rendering, you simply bind the texture that you want to render prior to drawing any primitives.